# How to create sub-folders if a folder already exists?

Tags: python

I would like to add more sub-folder, if a folder exists. I have managed to check whether the folder exists or not. But how can I create more folders in an already existing folder?

The name of the folder must also start at the point where the last folder was closed. For example, I have a folder called 'Hello'. In this folder there are already 10 subfolders, which are numbered `0, 1, 2..., 9`. Now if the folder already exists, I want to create 10 new subfolders. These must then start with 10, i.e. `10, 11, 12, ..., 19`.

How can I do that?

```
import os


folder_length = 10

def create_more():
    if wordExists(word):
        for folder in range(folder_length):
            folder = folder + 10
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(folder)))

    else:
        for folder in range(folder_length):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(folder)))
```

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The current code is not complete to be executed by others. At least, import statements, definition of `wordExists` and `sequence` variable are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can itterate through all the possible numbers and check if they exist

```py
folder_length = 10

def create_more():

    if wordExists(word):
        numOffset = 0
        while os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(startNum)):
            numOffset += 1
        for folder in range(folder_length):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(folder+numOffset)))


    else:
        for sequence in range(folder_length):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(folder)))
```

Comment: thx for your solution. but im getting a error message like FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists.